# setTimeout is not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, settimeout

I'm new in Javascript and i'm good familiar with `Thread.sleep` in Java. As far as i know, Javascript uses `setTimeout` which is similar to `Thread.sleep`.

I'm using `phantomjs` to print my thread:

```
function doThing(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
    }, 100);
}

for(var i=1; i<20; i++){    
    doThing(i);
}
phantom.exit();
```

***It prints nothing!!***

Can you please let me know, what's wrong here? :(

Help would be appreciated!!

***EDITED:***

I'm using Java program for calling `phantomjs script`.

Comment: try to do phantom.exit(); after the setTimeout

Comment: **NOT WORKING!! :(**

Comment: inside the setTimeout after console.log put if(i==19) phatom.exit(); and remove the phantom.exit(); which is at the last line of your code

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous. There is no way to `sleep` synchronously. In your code, you're exiting too early.

Comment: Still Not working !! :( I did tried to place `phantom.exit()` inside setTimeout but it prints only `20`. :(

Comment: In that case you should update the question, because that's not the problem described.

Comment: you can try my example code which will do the loop without for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function doThing(i, last){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(i);
        if (last) phantom.exit();
    }, 100 * i);
}

for(var i=1; i<20; i++){    
    doThing(i, i >= 19);
}
```

There are 2 fixes in this code (in comparison to origin):

1. phantom.exit() must be called just after last operation will be finished (in my revision I resolved this by using flag 'last' which will be set to true only for last iteration);
2. it's better to call setTimeout with slightly different timeout values, just to let them fire one by one (not so critical, but still it's better).

Comment: Not working!!! :( In your program `setTimeout` is not working!!.. It prints the number directly/

Comment: Just now I've run it using phantomjs and here is my result http://screencast.com/t/xHnaVx77bXZ7  As you may see - it's working

Comment: Have added couple of explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `setTimeout` is actually not the same as Thread.sleep at all. Javascript is single-threaded, and `setTimeout` just registers a callback to be executed after the provided amount of milliseconds, and then continues with the execution of the code following the `setTimeout` call. It doesn't halt the thread's execution.

Comment: Means, It will not execute as `Thread` simultaneously. For instance: printing 1 (5 seconds wait) 2 (5 seconds wait) 3(5 seconds wait) 4 (5 seconds wait) 5??

Comment: No, it means that after calling setTimeout (in your loop) which will execute the callback after 100 milliseconds, it will immediately continue with the next statement which is `phantom.exit()`, and that will happen before the 100 miliseconds have elapsed, and so will exit phantom before the callbacks have executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the program finish before you allow it to print anything.

You should delay the `phantom.exit()`. For example you can include it in a `setTimeout` which delays it long enough after finishing the loop.

For example change your last line with this:

```
setTimeout(phantom.exit, 5000)
```

After five seconds phantom will close, and you should see the values printed in the console.

Comment: I did as you said, but my loop is not working.. It prints `20` only.. :(

Comment: Try the proposed change

Comment: I have a question to ask, It will not execute as `Thread` simultaneously. For instance: printing 1 (5 seconds wait) 2 (5 seconds wait) 3(5 seconds wait) 4 (5 seconds wait) 5??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var i = 0;
function doThing(){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    if(i<20) setTimeout(doThing, 100);
    if(i>=20) phantom.exit();
}

setTimeout(doThing, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java and javascript are separate languages. So you can't compare features of those languages. setTimeout executes the block of code after a specified interval.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp